# how to add image in cell table view from format file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create table view that has many cell .

I want set image for any cell that this image from format file define. (for example I want add many image for many format file (for example when my file is .mp4 to use image that is mp4 or etc))

how can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it....
Crete image array and use below code.

```
cell.imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

it's set image in your cell according to indexPath.row
Hope this helped

Comment: my friend I want set image in my cell according format file (.mp4 & .mp3 & .wmv & ....) no according to indexPath.row

Comment: @MohammadK : Just put your images in array sequence vise which sequence you want and it worked.

Comment: you tell me that I add images in NSMutableArray and to use them later?

Comment: @MohammadK : check the answer. in answer code just put you NSMutableArray in place of myImageArray.